# Can Xcode Capture a GPU Frame in an XPC Service?

Tags: xcode, macos, debugging, gpu, metal

I have an XPC service that is using Metal to perform some basic blit operations between textures. I'd like to debug this using Xcode's GPU Frame Capture support but I can't find a way to target my XPC service for capture. I appear to only be able to target the host application.

If I launch my app and XPC service outside of Xcode and then attach to the service using Xcode's debugger, the button to initiate a GPU frame capture is not present.

Is there anyway to debug Metal textures within an XPC service? Even using Xcode's built-in QuickLook support for textures in an XPC service only yields a basic pop-up with addressing info for me.

Comment: Does anything change if you ensure that the `METAL_DEVICE_WRAPPER_TYPE` environment variable has a value of `1` in your XPC process? Have you tried using [programmatic frame capture](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/tools_profiling_and_debugging/metal_gpu_capture/performing_a_gpu_capture_programmatically?language=objc)?

Comment: I set that environment variable to 1 using Xcode's scheme editor for my service's `Run` action but it did not appear to have any effect. There's still no GPU Capture Camera icon for the service above the debugging panel. I then tried to programmatically capture one using `startCaptureWithDevice:`, performing my blit commands and then calling `stopCapture` but nothing happened. (i.e.: Xcode did not enter into the GPU debugger, there was no console output, etc. Those two calls just appeared to be no-ops.) The docs say "GPU Frame Capture must be enabled.", so maybe there's another setting?

Comment: @kennyc Have you found out how to do it?

Comment: @MateuszStompór Sorry, but I never did and eventually moved on to something else.